# tensorflow requires too much virtual main memory in GPU version

Tags: cuda, tensorflow

When I use the r1.4 GPU version of tensorflow, I found the virtual main memory it takes is too large, but when I use the CPU version, everything is ok. When I use `top` commands, here are the details:

VIRT: 15.726g, RES: 715824, SHR:295896, SWAP:0, CODE:2728, DATA:860644, MEM:2.2%

In the code, I use the following config:

```
config = tf.ConfigProto()
config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True
```

I think it isn't related to the main virtual memory.

Has someone encountered similar problems? I see somebody says that it is the problem caused by cuda, but no solutions found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is [Unified Virtual Address](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#unified-virtual-address-space) space which is a normal behavior since compute capability 2.0

> When the application is run as a 64-bit process, a single address space is used for the host and all the devices of compute capability 2.0 and higher.

So, it's expected to see the large amount of Virtual memory to be used by any CUDA program (such as TensorFlow gpu version)

Comment: Ah thanks! But in this case, my teammates tell me that their process can't start because Virtual memory was exhausted. Is there some solutions to this?

Comment: Can you please be more specific, what do you mean 'Their process can't start because Virtual memory was exhausted'? Any example, error message? Virtual memory space is a unique space for a process and does not affect other processes. In your shown example the resident memory (RES) is relatively small, so I cannot see the problem